# Neo4j Spring OGM query for list of entities always return distinct

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm

Lets say i have a graph:

```
A - follows -> B
A - follows -> C
```

Now, i have a query to get followers for both `B` and `C` (which should return me `A` 2 times).

```
MATCH (a)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(followers) 
WHERE a.username IN ['B','C']
RETURN followers
```

If i make this query through Neo4J browser, i get **2** records: `A` node 2 times. This is correct.

If i make the same query through Spring Repository i get a list with only **1** object (A).

So, through Spring's repository any query for entities performs as if i add `DISTINCT`, so there is no difference between regular query and `DISTINCT` one.

If i query for some property of a node, i.e. `A.username`, i get a list with two duplicate strings (as intended).

1. Is this behaviour expected?
2. Why ?
3. Is there a way to query fo full entities with duplicates, the same
   way that Cypher query works in Neo4J itself?

Answer (score 0):

In general this behaviour is correct:
The `A` is always the same and gets mapped as one object. It won't make any sense to create the very same object twice.

I don't know from your question what the query should map to. But assuming it should create `List<A>` for this query it is correct.
Returning the `a.username` will not map to any entity but can only get collected in a projection / `@QueryResult`. This result has no concept of equality or similar and will always get created for any returned "row" from the response.

Comment: Yes, my query should map to list <A>, and it does, but the list has no duplicates. I understand the concept of not mapping twice, but it is still confusing, that orm, in a sense, changes the query from the db's point of view.

Comment: Typically you would have a `Collection` on `A` that would then contain both `Follower` nodes. What you are thinking of would always create just pairs and you would not know in object `A1` with only `B` that there is also a `A2` that relates to `C`.